# Delphi cxGrid rowcount

Tags: excel, delphi, rowcount

I use cxGrid and I want import a excel file to cxgrid. I wrote this code a function.

But, its wrong, because cxGrid dont know RowCount and ColCount. 
I would like know, what can I use, what is similar?
Help me!
Thank you!

```
function Xls_To_cxGrid(AGrid: TcxGrid; AXLSFile: string): Boolean;

const
  xlCellTypeLastCell = $0000000B;
var
  XLApp, Sheet: OLEVariant;
  RangeMatrix: Variant;
  x, y, k, r: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    XLApp.Visible := False;
    XLApp.Workbooks.Open(AXLSFile);
    Sheet := XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)].WorkSheets[1];

    Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;
    x := XLApp.ActiveCell.Row;
    y := XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;

      AGrid.RowCount := x;
      AGrid.ColCount := y;

    RangeMatrix := XLApp.Range['A1', XLApp.Cells.Item[X, Y]].Value;
    k := 1;
    repeat
      for r := 1 to y do
        AGrid.Cells[(r - 1), (k - 1)] := RangeMatrix[K, R];
      Inc(k, 1);
      AGrid.RowCount := k + 1;
    until k > x;
    RangeMatrix := Unassigned;

  finally
    if not VarIsEmpty(XLApp) then
    begin
      XLApp.Quit;
      XLAPP := Unassigned;
      Sheet := Unassigned;
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cxGrid is just a container for ChartViews, TableViews, CardViews and BandedTableViews. Being a container, it does not know anything about rows and columns. Because you want to replace a StringGrid I suggest using a (non-DB) TableView.

To get a TableView...

- ...open the grid customization form (click on "Customize..." in the grid's "Structure Navigator" in the form designer).
- Go to the "Views" tab and click "Add View...". Choose "Table" (**not** "DB Table"!).
- On the "Structure" tab right-click on the cxGrid1Level1 symbol, choose "Select View" and the new TableView.
- You can now go back to the "Views" tab and delete the **DB** TableView (cxGrid1DBTableView1).

(See also the DX help topic "Grid Levels" unter the heading "Specifying Associated Grid Views".)

Instead of "RowCount" you would then use `YourView.DataController.RecordCount`. "ColCount" would be `YourView.ColumnCount`. You can access cell values with `YourView.DataController.Values[...]`. To speed up the populating the view I'd surround it with

```
YourView.DataController.BeginUpdate;
try
  YourView.DataController.RecordCount := x;
  // ...
finally
  YourView.DataController.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: The cxGrid is just a container for ChartViews,TableViews, CardViews and BandedTableViews. Being a container, it does not know anything about rows and columns.

Comment: @alzaimar, I incorporated your comment.

Comment: My tableview name is: cxGrid1DBTableView1, and i use that: cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.RecordCount := x; But it undeclared, and i tried AGrid.cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.RecordCount := x;, but it's too. How can I use, what you wrote me? And i dont want use StringGrid, because i had a StringGrid and I want replace that new db grid. Thanks! :)

Comment: @GodGirl: As I wrote you should use a **non-DB** view. I'll edit my answer with some steps how to achieve that.

Comment: "•On the "Structure" tab right-click on the cxGrid1Level1 symbol, choose "Select View" and the new TableView."